# How to get xml response sent to our webpage/url in C#

Tags: c#, xml

We would like to ask how to retrieve/get the xml response coming from a third party website. We just supply the redirectUrl and the xml response will be sent to it.

We have tried the code below to retrieve the xml details but it's not retrieving the data.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument(); //xml doc used for xml parsing


        xdoc.Load("http://xxx/Home/Index"); 

        XmlNodeList xNodelst = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/Data/Quote/Product"); //reading node so that we can traverse thorugh the XML

        foreach (XmlNode xNode in xNodelst)//traversing XML 
        {
            Sessions.PartNumber = xNode["PartNum"].InnerText;
        }

        return View();

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you share the XML response that was returned from the third-part website to the question? Thanks.

Comment: You are returning view from the action method. But it is not clear what are you doing in the view. So can not guess what could be the issue.